# How can I recursively add a string to a filename, if contents contain a specific word?

Tags: bash

I have a files in the following structure:

```
Directory1/Subdir N/filename.ext
Directory2/Subdir N/Subdir X/filename.ext
```

How can I:

1. Find all files with a extension ".ext"
2. Find "string" in file contents, and if "string" is found:
3. Rename the file to the original filename, but with filename.string.ext

My goal is to search a bunch of txt files for a couple of Swedish words, and if that word is found, rename the file to filename.sv.ext - if it's not, rename it to filename.en.ext.

Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

The following line matches a bunch of english words, and if the file contains any of them, rename it to filename.en.srt. It does not touch files already named filename.en.srt or filename.sv.srt.

```
# Rename English subtitles to filename.en.srt
find . ! -name '*.sv.srt' ! -name '*.en.srt' -name '*.srt' -exec sh -c 'grep -i -q -e yes -e maybe -e right -e left -e friend -e call -e leave -e stupid -e while -e dark -e fool -e mercy -e emotion -e find -e morning -e subtitles -e picture -e say -e nothing -e always -e people -e heart "$1" && mv "$1" "${1%.srt}.en.srt"' x '{}' \;


# Rename Swedish subtitles to filename.sv.srt
find . ! -name '*.sv.srt' ! -name '*.en.srt' -name '*.srt' -exec sh -c 'grep -i -q -e undertexter -e komma -e allt -e kollega -e arbeta -e arbete -e morgon -e lycklig -e kanske -e lugn -e tycker -e liksom -e okej -e orkar -e telefon -e historia -e ingen -e beredd -e kunna -e trodde -e tror "$1" && mv "$1"  ${1%.srt}.sv.srt"' x '{}' \;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your problem is nothing difficult. Have you already tried to solve it? How? Can you show us your code? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
find -name '*.ext'  -exec sh -c 'grep -q string "$1" && mv "$1" "${1%.ext}.string.ext"' x '{}' \;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!!
Heja Norge! :-)

Comment: +1 for one line and `grep`. I for some reason expected for read loop with `break` if found to be faster than `grep`, but doing a quick test now, I think it's quite a bit slower, would be interesting how they optimized it.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like below. Pseudocodish, without knowing exactly what strings you want/how you want to tell file language, but should work with a few edits you can make.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

#globstar is essentially the recursive version of *".ext", which gets all .ext in this dir
#can alternatively use find if you have an old shell version
#also note this descends the same way as `find .`, but you can change it to 
#"/home/somedir/"**/*".ext" or something
for file in **/*".ext"; do 

  #check if the file is a regular file (not symlink, dir)
  if [[ -f $file ]]; then

    #read in the file line by line (might be a faster way to do this)
    while read line; do

      #replace somestring, with whatever string you want to check for
      #this checks if it exists on the current line, mvs the file, and breaks the loop
      [[ $line == *somestring* ]] && echo "$file" "${file%.ext}.string.ext" && break

    done < "$file"
  fi
done
```

So you don't break anything, I have `echo` instead of `mv` in the script above, replace it when you think it will work and probably test it on a short dir tree anyway.

**Update: Using `find` for older bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(find . -name '*.ext' -type f); do
  while read line; do
    [[ $line == *test* ]] && echo "$file" "${file%.ext}.string.ext" && break
  done < "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch BroSlow!

While I haven't been able to test your solution just yet, I'm very grateful for your effort.

It turns out my Synology DS411j only runs bash 3.2 which does not support the globstar parameter (introduced in bash 4).

I'll just ilveboot a GNU/Linux installation in a VM and run it, just as soon as I've installed VMware or something :-)

Thanks!

Comment: @mescon No problem, I updated my answer in case you're curious how the for loop would look with `find`, though as long we're using `find` might as well one line it, so `Håkon Hægland`'s answer is probably best if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the update!
I ended up with Håkon's suggestion... the below line renames files that contain any of the words. I have one similar, that renames to .sv.srt if it contains any of a bunch of specific swedish words.

My Plex can now identify languages :)


    find . ! -name '*.sv.srt' ! -name '*.en.srt' -name '*.srt' -exec sh -c 'grep -i -q -e yes -e maybe -e right -e left -e friend -e call -e leave -e stupid -e while -e dark -e fool -e mercy -e emotion -e find -e morning -e
subtitles -e picture -e say -e nothing -e always -e people -e heart "$1" && mv "$1" "${1%.srt}.en.srt"' x '{}' \;